# Changing the default punctuation of the questions in `exams2moodle()` function

Tags: r-exams

I would like to generate a bunch of exams with schoice questions using the `exams2moodle()` function. Each question will have 4 alternative answers with one and only one TRUE answer. That's pretty normal but I would like to change the deafult behaviour for the marks. The usual behaviour is that you get 100% if you select the right answer and -33% if you select one of the 3 bad answers, but I would like to change this to 100% but -25%. It's that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not officially supported. Note that the reason for the default negative points of 1/#false is that then random guessing has an expectation of 0. Your suggestion would still have a slightly positive expectation.

For `exams2moodle()` (but not for all other interfaces) one can use a somewhat hacky workarund:

```
ee <- exams_eval()
ee$pointvec <- function(correct) {
  if(is.logical(correct)) correct <- paste(as.integer(correct), collapse = "")
  c(pos = 1, neg = -1/nchar(correct))
}
```

This yields:

```
ee$pointvec("1000")
##  pos   neg 
## 1.00 -0.25
```

And in case of `exams2moodle()` the `$pointvec` is the only part of the evaluation strategy that is used. Hence, you can then do:

```
exams2moodle(..., schoice = list(eval = ee))
```

leading to the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks Achim!! It works. Of course, you are the creator of the package!! Thanks again

Comment: Note: I just updated the `ee$pointvec(correct)` function so that it is a bit more robust and can also be used in `cloze` exercises for `exams2moodle()`.

Comment: Hi @AchimZeileis, can you explain how this could be used in a cloze exercise with schoice and num items?

Comment: See this discussion in the forum on R-Forge: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33969&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337